# Help with basic trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

it's been many years since I was at school and I never did algebra so I'm having a real hard time understanding trigonometry again.
ALL the sites just say use this easy formula to calculate it:

```
Sin(q) = Opposite / Hypotenuse
Cos(q) = Adjacent / Hypotenuse 
Tan(q) = Opposite / Adjacent
```

Thing is, I have no idea what all this means... I'm familiar with using Sin and Cos to draw circles but thats it.

[image: right-triangle]

Ok, so say I have A, C and b. How do I get the length of the hypotenuse?
I'd love someone to explain all this in easy non-algebraic ways.

Calculations using *, + and / will make it a lot easier for me.

Comment: Don't forget that $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Comment: @Sigur, I dont know what that means. (I do understand squaring though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that $\cos A=\frac bc$, so $c=\frac b{\cos A}$  You might look at [Wikipedia on right triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle).

Comment: The second value works but what is that first one? I'd really love to understand how this all works in relation to those formulas, but everything I try reading just uses implied algebra constantly and stuff like a2+b2=c2 without explaining each component.

Comment: @Craig:  the first is just translating the definition of cosine that you gave in your question.  For angle A, the adjacent side is b, and the hypotenuse is c.  Then I cross multiplied to get the equation into the form $c=$stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have A, C and b.

Law of sines: $\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=\frac{c}{\sin(C)}$.

Law of cosines: $a^2+b^2-2 a b \cos(C)=c^2$.

From law of sines by algebra: $a=\frac{c \sin(A)}{\sin(C)}$.

Apply this to the law of cosines: $(\frac{c \sin(A)}{\sin(C)})^2+b^2-2*\frac{c \sin(A)}{\sin(C)}*b*\cos(C)=c^2$. Open and simplify a bit:

$b^2 + (\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(C)})^2-2*\frac{c \sin(A)}{\sin(C)}*b*\cos(C)=0$

Solve $c$:

$c=b \frac{\sin(C)}{2 \sin(A) \cos(C)}+\frac{\sin(A)}{2 b \sin(C) \cos(C)}$.

$\frac{\sin(C)}{\cos(C)} = \tan(c)$, thus

$c=b \frac{\tan(C)}{2 \sin(A)}+\frac{\sin(A)}{2 b \sin(C) \cos(C)}$.

That is probably too complicated...

Comment: Yes, in response to your last statement...